# Проблема с переменными средами Windows

Tags: cmd, windows-10, path

Хотел добавь Python в окружение, что-бы не приходилось постоянно полный путь писать. Добавиться он добавился, но что-то пошло не так.
[image: Переменные среды пользователя]

При проверке set path

```
>set path
Path=...;C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Programs\Python;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Но

```
> python
"python" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

P.s: При ручном вызове с полным путем установки python запускается нормально

Comment: Я бы начал с избавления от кириллицы в путях.

Comment: От кириллицы избавился - не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался.
Проблема была в расположении непосредственно python и использовании path.
Если кратко, то python.exe находился в подкаталоге, каталога указанного в path.